# Do amounts *always* take singular verbs?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I know amounts and quantities usually take singular verbs even if they are plural nouns but what about this sentence? :

-There ........ two dollars in my wallet.
A) is
B) are

-Which is the right answer and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're both right. Use *is* if you're referring to the amount of money, *are* if you're referring to the number of dollars.

Comment: **Two dollars** are a dollar+a dollar so **are** seems more appropriate to me, however, if it were one paper I'd go with **is**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Robusto** commented:

- They're both correct. Use **is** if you're referring to the **amount of money** and **are** if you're referring to the **number of dollars**.

Comment: There could be a multiple of X, but always only one 1 grand total or amount of X.  *There are two dollars in my wallet* = *I have two 1-dollar bills in my wallet*, *There is two dollars in my wallet* might = *I have 8 quarters.*

Comment: @LawrenceC I'm not familiar with *8 quarters*. Could you expand your comment, please?

Comment: A quarter is a coin worth 25% of a dollar in the U.S.

Comment: @LawrenceC Aha, so the 8 quarters are just 8 coins each worth 1/4 of a dollar. As there doesn't exist a 2-dollar bill this might be a real usage.

Comment: There are 2-dollar bills but they are pretty rare.